# Splitting python string by all delimiters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have the following words :

```
a. 'abc_bank_portfolios'
b. 'abc-bank-portfolios'
c. 'abc/bank portfolios'
d. 'abc.bank.portfolios'
```

For all of the above examples I want the output as : `['abc', 'bank', 'portfolios']`

In short I want to split a string using any delimiter

My Code looks as follows :

```
import re
list_of_words = re.findall(r"[\w']+", <input_string>)
```

This `works for all cases except when there is an underscore`.

If I do : `re.findall(r"[\w']+", "abc_bank_portfolios")` , the output is `[abc_bank_portfolios]`. I want it as `['abc', 'bank', 'portfolios']` even for the `underscore` case.

What am i doing wrong here ? How to get the desired output for all cases ?

Comment: Use `re.split()`, it allows you to specify the delimiter as a regexp.

Comment: The reason for your result is that `\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscore, so `_` is not a delimiter.

Comment: The two answers to this question take opposite approaches for defining how broad to be with the definition of “delimiter”, and probably neither work well in edge cases. What do *you* mean by it? What about accented characters (eg. `é`), other special characters (`~`, `|`, `*`, `#`, , non-breaking spaces, newlines, etc.), multiple delimiters in a row (eg. `"abc, bank, portfolios"`)? If you won’t see any edge cases then the solutions below might be fine, but if somebody has `"my~résumé"`, they both fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\w` matches letters, numbers, and underscore. You'll need to be more specific about what you consider word characters.

```
list_of_words = re.findall(r"[a-z0-9']+", input_string, re.I)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you it looks like you *know* the delimiters (`_`, `-`, `/`, `.`, ), but don't know the available characters for each field (i.e: are numbers allowed? what about `@`? etc...), I'd suggest using [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), which behaves similarly to [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

The regex you need is `r'[_\-/\. ]'` to match:

- `_` - underscore
- `\-` - a backslash (escaped because otherwise it indicates a range)
- `/` - a forward slash
- `\.` - a period (escaped because otherwise it means "*any character*")
- - a space

```py
import re

inputs = [
  'abc_bank_portfolios',
  'abc-bank-portfolios',
  'abc/bank portfolios',
  'abc.bank.portfolios',
]

for item in inputs:
  print(re.split(r'[_\-/\. ]', item))
```